# Displaying a video in a dialog

Tags: android

Is it possible to display a video in a pop up dialog in android ?

For example, If I share a video with somebody before that I want a preview of what I am sharing. So I need to check/play that video in the pop up dialog. Please guide me as to which apis to look for in android regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

The [`VideoView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) view is what is usually used to display video. You'd use this view in a [custom dialog box](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog).

Comment: I tried this , but it says the Video cannot be played. Any suggestions. I checked other posts in stackOverflow also, they also face same problem. Is there any workaround ?

Comment: Okay we can do this way.
1. Create a custom dialog. This custom dialog must have a SurfaceView.
2.Use the MediaPlayer instance to play, start, pause and do all kinds of operations you want.
3. dont forget to use SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFER and also setBackgroud of surfaceView as TRANSPARENT. or else it will play but you wont be able to see video.